# How to display all services and version that runs on a host?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to display all services and their versions that runs on a host using ports from 1 to 1023, in this way:

```
ssh, OpenSSH 5.9p1 Debian 5ubuntu1 (protocol 2.0)
smtp, Postfix smtpd
http, Apache httpd 2.2.22 ((Ubuntu))
rpcbind
imap, Courier Imapd (released 2011)
ssl/imap, Courier Imapd (released 2011)
```

I know how to display them but not in the format above:

nmap -p 1-1023 -sV host

LATER EDIT:

I managed to display only the services without any extra unuseful text:

```
nmap -p 1-1023 -sV host | head -n -5 | tail -n +7
```

Which outputs:

```
8/tcp   open  http       BitTornado tracker T-0.3.18
21/tcp  open  ftp        vsftpd 2.3.5
22/tcp  open  ssh        OpenSSH 5.9p1 Debian 5ubuntu1 (protocol 2.0)
23/tcp  open  telnet     Linux telnetd
25/tcp  open  smtp       Postfix smtpd
80/tcp  open  http       Apache httpd 2.2.22 ((Ubuntu))
111/tcp open  rpcbind
143/tcp open  imap       Courier Imapd (released 2011)
158/tcp open  ssh        OpenSSH 5.9p1 Debian 5ubuntu1.1 (protocol 2.0)
165/tcp open  ssh        OpenSSH 5.9p1 Debian 5ubuntu1.1 (protocol 2.0)
177/tcp open  ftp        vsftpd 2.3.5
210/tcp open  ssh        OpenSSH 5.9p1 Debian 5ubuntu1.1 (protocol 2.0)
993/tcp open  ssl/imaps?
```

Now I am really curious how can I get rid of the first two columns.

Comment: Does `nmap -p 1-1023 -sV host | head -n -5 | tail -n +7 | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4` work?

Comment: No really. It ouputs something else. #open
open 
open 
open 
open 
open 
 rpcbind
 imap
 ssh
 ssh
 ftp
 ssh
 ssl/imaps?#

Comment: Try changing the `3,4` to `4,5` real quick.

Comment: @Seth No. Not working.

Comment: @AdrianGeorge This one works for sure, just tested it and it's exactly what you want `nmap -p 1-1023 -sV host | head -n -5 | tail -n +7 | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $3))}'`

Comment: @mbiber Indeed, it works. Please answer the question so I can mark it as valid answer. What exactly awk does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works for sure, just tested it and it's exactly what you want:

```
nmap -p 1-1023 -sV host | head -n -5 | tail -n +7 | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $3))}'
```

`index` finds the 3rd column and returns its position to `substring` which then marks that position in whole line `$0`. All of this is then sent to `print` which displays it. Default field separator in awk is whitespace (spaces, TABs, newlines) so no need in using -F switch.

Comment: Awesome! I was trying to achieve this with `cut`, but it doesn't work so well with whitespace. I should really spend some time learning awk.

Comment: Can also remove the head/tail bits: `nmap ... | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+\/..p$/ {print substr($0, index($0, $3))}'` -- the awk regex should catch  services listening on tcp or udp.

Comment: @Seth: `... | cut -b 15-`